# Sonarqube - remove this useless assignment to variable "x"

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

Variable "x" is not being used. How can i change this code? When  just remove "x" appear this message in setX: This expression is not callable.
Type 'String' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined

`const [x, setX] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);`

```
 if (data?.status && data.status < 500) {
      setX(t('login:invalid'));
    } else {
      authOnSuccess(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove property `x` from array if this is unused

```js
const [setX] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
```

Comment: It doesn't work :/ This expression is not callable. Type 'String' has no call signatures.ts(2349) Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined

Comment: It's because setX type is string or undefined, but you invoke it as a function